# Excel Cells not formatting to date

Tags: excel

I am unable to format a column into date format unless I click into the cell then click out.

This data is exported from a third party application to .xlsx format. When I open the file in Excel and try to format what should be the date column, the date formatting will not take affect until I click into the cell as if I were going to make changes then exit/click out of the cell.

Image 1 raw data

[image]

image 2 setting the formatting

[image]

image 3, clicking into a cell.

[image]

image 4, clicking out of the cell.

[image]

Notice the rest of the rows in image 4 that rows 4 and beyond have retained their original formatting, and the only ones that have the new formatting are the ones I clicked into then clicked out. Selecting a cell without going into it also keeps the original formatting. While clicking into a cell then out is not a huge problem, when you get thousands of rows this gets annoying. Any fix or workaround you can suggest?

Comment: That is because they are imported as text that look like dates and not true dates.  You can use text to columns to convert wholesale.

Comment: Can you be most specific in terms of "Use text to columns"?

Comment: Select the whole column run text to columns, walk through the steps, on the last step choose date. hit finish.

Answer (score 2):

I used to "Text to Column" wizard and converted the data into dates.